# How to compare the values of property in wso2 esb?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

How can I compare the values of property in wso2 esb i.e I want to do filter operation that if `property2.value== property1.value` then it should do further processing else it should drop. But how to do this I am not getting?
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an example of a sequence comparing to properties and executing two filters:

```
<property name="propertyA" value="'abc'"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="propertyA" expression="get-property('propertyA')"/>
</log>
<property name="propertyB" value="'abc'"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="propertyB" expression="get-property('propertyB')"/>
</log>
<property name="propertyCompare" expression="get-property('propertyA') = get-property('propertyB')"/>
<log level="custom">
    <property name="propertyCompare" expression="get-property('propertyCompare')"/>
</log>
<filter  source="get-property('propertyCompare')" regex="true">
    <then>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="filterA" expression="'worked'"/>
         </log>
    </then>
</filter>
<filter  xpath="get-property('propertyA') = get-property('propertyB')">
    <then>
        <log level="custom">
           <property name="filterB" expression="'worked'"/>
         </log>
    </then>
</filter>
```